# Trying to convert an object array into XML, can't get object headers

Tags: java, arrays, xml, object, xmlencoder

I'm using this XML converter, but I am not getting the object header to wrap each object's properties... I can't find a method in the encoder class to do this either.

The code iterates through my array and lists all objects that are not null.

```java
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\David Laptop\\Documents\\Doc1.xml");
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
for( int x = 0; x < people.length;x++)
  if (people[x] != null)
  {
    //header here?
    encoder.writeObject(people[x].getName());
    encoder.writeObject(people[x].getTelephoneNumber());
    encoder.writeObject(people[x].getEmailAddress());    
  }
}
encoder.close();
```

I get this outcome:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<java version="1.7.0_40" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
string
dad</string  string 35235 /string 
string email /string
</java>
```

If I do more object entries then it ends up being a big list which isn't helpful as another function I want to implement is reading from an XML file into the array... any help on that would also be useful!

EDIT: New information based on the answer given:

So is there no way to make this happen without a no-arg constructor? I've implemented the Serializable into both classes for good measure... I'm using this line to add new objects:

```java
mybook1.addRecord(new newPerson(Name,telephoneNumber,emailAddress));
```

which uses this:

```java
public void addRecord(newPerson c) 
{
    people[numOfRecords] = c; 
    numOfRecords++;  
}
```

below is the object itself:

```java
public class newPerson implements java.io.Serializable 
{     

private String Name; 
private String telephoneNumber; 
private String emailAddress;  

public newPerson(String n, String t, String e) 
{ //local variables n,t,e only used in this method
    Name = n;
    telephoneNumber = t;
    emailAddress = e;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializing Object instance variables will result in a hard to main process where you will be forced to decode the values back one by one.

It would be wiser and easier to deal with when serializing your whole `People` objects:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\David Laptop\\Documents\\Doc1.xml");
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);
for( int x = 0; x < people.length;x++)
  if (people[x] != null)
  {
    encoder.writeObject(people[x]);    
  }
}
encoder.close();
```

Meanwhile, you have to make sure that your `People` class statisfies the [JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) conventions which basiclly has to be `Serializable` and should provide a public no-arg constructor.

Comment: What is the problem with a no-arg constructor? If you add a new constructor the compiler won't add a no-arg one for you and you have to explicitely add it so it can be used upon serialization.
Please accept the answer if it helped tackling the issue.